# Fiddler to request HTTP requests with timing respected

Tags: fiddler, session-replay

Can HTTP request be replayed using Fiddler with caputered session timing respected?

I tried to replay a session with fiddler but the replay sends requests to the maximum speed ignoring the time of capture.

I tried to add this to onBeforeRequest() function:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("example.com") && oSession.uriContains("page.html")) {
    // I tried this
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // and this
    // oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "30"; 
}
```

but doesn't work very well and I must to repeat this for every captured URI.

I need to replay a captured session but the requests must be sent with the same delay as recorded. Is it possible?

Comment: what you've done so far? did you try it with Fiddler? did you google about it capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler does not itself attempt to respect relative timings when replaying requests.

You could write script or an extension that would do so, based on each `Session` object's `oTimers` data.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution, it maybe useful to others:

```
static function DoTimedReplay() {
    var oSessions = FiddlerApplication.UI.GetSelectedSessions();
    if (oSessions.Length == 0) {
        oSessions = FiddlerApplication.UI.GetAllSessions();
        if (oSessions.Length == 0) {
            FiddlerObject.alert("No session available.");
            return;
        }
    }

    FiddlerObject.StatusText = "Start replay";
    var iStart = Environment.TickCount;
    for (var x:int = 0; x < oSessions.Length; x++) {
        var iDelay:Int32 = x == 0 ? 0 :
            System.Math.Round(
                (oSessions[x].Timers.ClientBeginRequest - oSessions[x - 1].Timers.ClientBeginRequest).TotalMilliseconds
            );
        replay(oSessions[x], iStart + iDelay);
    }
    FiddlerObject.StatusText = "Replay Done";
}

static function replay(oSession: Session, iDelay: Int32) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oSession["X-Replayed"]))
            return;
        try {
            var oSD = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();
            oSD.Add("X-Replayed", "True");
            while (iDelay > Environment.TickCount) {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            FiddlerApplication.oProxy.SendRequest(oSession.oRequest.headers, oSession.requestBodyBytes, oSD);
        } catch(ex) {
            var iTickCount = Environment.TickCount + 10000;
            while (iTickCount > Environment.TickCount) {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Why does your catch block pump for 10 seconds? 
Your code presumes that the Sessions are sorted in order of ClientBeginRequest, which isn't always a safe assumption to make.